# How can I find an application if i don't know its GUID

Tags: nsis, guid, uninstallation

In order to compare versions, I have to find out if my app has been already installed. 
I use registry to store whole necessary inforamtion and it would be very useful if i could somehow read strings from registry. Main issue here is that I don't know my own GUID which was randomized during previous installation.

To generate my registry path I wrote following script:

```
Function .onInit
    ${If} ${RunningX64}
        StrCpy $R0 "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $R0 "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

MainSection:

```
Section "Main" sec
System::Call 'ole32::CoCreateGuid(g .s)'
Pop $0
WriteRegStr HKLM "$R0\$0" 'DisplayVersion' '${AppVersion}'
SectionEnd
```

So, basically I need to find a way to read `DisplayVersion` string. I wish there was some variation of `FindFirst` but for registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EnumRegKey` to enumerate registry keys:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section

StrCpy $0 0
loop:
    EnumRegKey $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" $0
    StrCmp $1 "" done
    ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$1" "DisplayName"
    ${If} $2 == "My Application Name"
        ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$1" "DisplayVersion"
        DetailPrint "TODO: Compare $2 to version here..."
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $0 $0 + 1
    Goto loop
done:

SectionEnd
```